# Recognizing the type of triangular in C

Tags: c

in this project I have to recognize the type of the triangular by getting their sides as input .
compiling is fine but the result is not matching with the real math .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int a , b , c;

int A,B,C;
A=a*a  ;
B=b*b ;
C=c*c ;
printf("Enter the biggest side\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Enter the second side\n");
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("Enter the third side\n");
scanf("%d",&c);

if(A=B+C) printf("Right");

if(A<B+C) printf("OBTUSE");

else if(a<b+c)  printf("ACUTE");


return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: `A=a*a` You need to set the `a` values (and all the other values) before using them. Move those assignments to be *after* they are set by the `scanf` calls.

Comment: Also , `if(A=B+C)` needs to be `if(A==B+C)`

Comment: And for best practice should always check the return value of function calls such as `scanf`.

Comment: For best practice, compile with `-Wall`. It would have flagged the assignment `A = a * a;` as using the _uninitialized_ value of `a`

Answer (score 0):

the if statement has a '=' instead of a '==' and the calculations need to be set after the scanf functions.
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a, b, c;

    int A, B, C;

    printf("Enter the biggest side\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter the second side\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &b);
    printf("Enter the third side\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &c);

    A = a * a;
    B = b * b;
    C = c * c;

    if (A == (B + C)) printf("Right");

    if (A < (B + C)) printf("OBTUSE");

    else 
        printf("ACUTE");


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but the condition for the obtuse triangle should be `if (A > B + C)`.